# How to sort WP_Post Object array by object field in php?

Tags: posts, wp-query, sort

I have a php code as shown below in which I want to sort `WP_Post Object` array by object field `post_date`.

```
if ( $search ) {
    $area_query = new \WP_Query( [
        's'           => $search,
        'post_type'   => 'abc-xyz',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ] );
}
```

This is what I have tried in order to sort `WP_Post object` array but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if ( $search ) {
    $area_query = new \WP_Query( [
        's'           => $search,
        'post_type'   => 'abc-xyz',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ] );
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it sorts `WP_Post` object array order by date.

Comment: You shouldn't be directly accessing the posts array in `WP_Query`, that's not how `WP_Query` works. If you want an array of `WP_Post` objects you should use `get_posts` instead.  Also if `$search` is false then `$area_query` is undefined.

Comment: Also, the `order` argument doesn't sort the object field. Those are query variables, not class variables, they are unconnected, and they have a predefined list of valid values as documented in the official `WP_Query` document. No sorting of the objects happens in PHP, and the order is the order the rows are returned from the database query. Remember, WP is not an OO framework.

Comment: I agree, I need to use `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`. I am wondering if you can give me pointer how I can use it.  Also, if `$search` is false then it would go inside the else statement. I haven't posted the complete question.

Comment: The official documentation will show you how to use `get_posts`, but keep in mind it has performance costs if used incorrectly. `WP_Query` is superior. It's also expected that questions are complete and self-contained

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it sorts WP_Post object array order by date.

WordPress/PHP does not sort the objects, that's not how this works. Additionally, the `sort` argument does not take the name of object fields. The two are not connected. The order of the posts is determined by the results of rows from the post table returned by the SQL query.

Instead, `sort` is a parameter used to construct an SQL query. [If we look at the documentation we can see the valid values](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters), so you are already using the correct order parameters:

```php
$area_query = new \WP_Query( [
    's'           => $search,
    'post_type'   => 'abc-xyz',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
] );
```

The above code is asking the database for posts, srted by date in ascending order ( e.g. 1AD, 2AD, 500AD, 1000AD, 2000AD, etc ). It may be that you wanted the reverse.

Note that if you are storing the data in post meta, this will not work, the `date` here is the date the post was published.